# How to re-add click listener after dynamically changing innerHTML?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, replace, addeventlistener

I'm trying to convert  tags into  tags in a Shopify store in content that's dynamically loaded through a 3rd party app, meaning the HTML is added after the page finishes loading.  Before I do the conversion, the  tags already have 'click' event listeners added to them through the 3rd party script.

My current code looks like this:

```
var widgetHTML = $(".cbb-frequently-bought-selector-list").html();
widgetHTML = widgetHTML.replace(/<a /g, '<span ').replace(/<\/a>/g, '</span>');
$('.cbb-frequently-bought-selector-list').html(widgetHTML);
```

After this code executes, the original 'click' event listeners are gone.

Is there a way to temporarily save a reference to all existing 'click' event listeners on all  tags, then execute the above code, then add the 'click' event listeners back onto the new  tags that replaced the  tags?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's event delegation like this:

```
$(document).on('click','your_element_selector', function() {
   // your code    
});
```

Comment: Also it is highly recommended to do `$(<nearest static container>).on` instead of `$(document).on`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for marking a question as a duplicate

Comment: Yea well it was quite harsh from your side, i doubt u go and comment to every answer you believe was answered before in the same manner